# Formatar datatime no Ionic

Tags: ionic, typescript

Bom dia, criei um input datatime porém ele me retorna a data da seguinte forma:2019-04-26T11:43:17Z, e o banco não aceita esse formato, precisava que me retornasse assim: 26/04/2019 11:43:17. Como faço essa formatação ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
moment('2019-04-26T11:43:17Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Comment: cara deu certo, Valeu! porém a hora ele está retornando errada, coloca uns horários aleatórios

Comment: está retornando 3hrs mais cedo do que é recebido, por exemplo se a pessoa digita 12:00:00 retorna 9:00:00

Comment: tenta por .toISOString() na sua data antes de formatar com o format

Comment: como ficaria a sintaxe, sabendo que minha data eu pego de this.inputs.data ?

Comment: this.inputs.data.toISOString()

Comment: Diz que toISOSString() não é uma função, mas tranquilo, já me ajudou muito!

Comment: Opa, cara, qual o tipo do teu this.inputs.data ? se for implementação da interface Date ele deve ter essa função. 
o que tá acontecendo é que tua data tá sendo "convertida" no UTC. 
Eu não sei se vai dar certo, mas você pode por o Z no seu format , ficando assim :
moment('2019-04-26T11:43:17Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm Z')